# Push data between view controllers but no NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to push data from one view controller to another which has been partially successful with the following code.

```
TestViewResultController *TVRC = (TestViewResultController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVRC"];

TVRC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:TVRC animated:YES completion:nil];

TVRC.lblSectionPercentageBox.text = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

TVRC.lblSectionLetterBox.text = cell.textLabel.text;

TVRC.lblModuleIdent.text = theText40;
```

This pushes the required data from a tableview to a view controller. The storyboard is embedded in a navigation controller, so I was expecting a navigation bar to appear in the view-controller (TestViewResultController) but this does not work. No navigation bar is shown even if i add:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

in ViewDidLoad.

However if I:

```
    TestViewResultController *TVRC = (TestViewResultController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TVRC"];

    TVRC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:TVRC animated:YES];

TVRC.lblSectionPercentageBox.text = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

TVRC.lblSectionLetterBox.text = cell.textLabel.text;

TVRC.lblModuleIdent.text = theText40;
```

I get the Navigationbar but it does not push the values for cell.detailTextLabel, theText & cell.textLabel.

What am I doing wrong here please?

Comment: in short: Everything, this is a huge mess, use the MVC pattern.
in long: When you try to set the label's text, the label is still nill. Create string properties to the second view controller, set these before you push it, and in the viewController's viewDidLoad method set the label's text to the appropriate property. It will work, but this is a nasty solution...